How can we use same import paths in PyCharm and Blender?
A friend and I are working on an add-on to Blender. It does some complicated geometry work and so we have developed the code using PyCharm and pytest. We have a handful of commands that get added to the menus, with all those classes in one file. The helper functions want to be in separate files, imported into the main script that gets loaded into Blender.
Imports that work in PyCharm, such as
from foo import Foo

Work fine in PyCharm but the files are not found in Blender. If we move the files into a subfolder "modules", they are found in Blender, but in PyCharm we would have to say
from modules/foo import Foo

So that won't do in PyCharm and our tests won't run.
I think we could set up a try/except that will try first one import statement and then the other, but that seems nasty.
I've read other Q/A about this, but they all seem to be from long ago and I am hoping that there is a more modern and effective way to get what we need. I'm open to being told to read things or watch tutorials, and, of course also open to a really easy answer posted here.
Thanks!

You can try setting up a symlink between the blender environment and your pycharm environment so the files are at both locations at the same time and update accordingly

Tempting! Seems iffy to have a symlink in something that's in Git and GitHub, though ... Thanks!

That's how one of the most  (if not the most) popular extension  for blender development for VScode works, so I don't think it's that problematic. YMMV https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development

Thanks! I'll see if that helps us.

All imports in all the files in your addon should be relative: from . import foo, from .. import bar, from .foobar import Foobar, etc. Do not use the wildcard imports: from X import *. Do not use import from a package: from A import B where A is a part of your addon. Do not import the addon from within the addon: import my_addon or from my_addon import B. This will resolve the circular import.
__package__ will be the addon's root folder name which is the __init__.py file.
If you want to access any part of the addon like for using with pytest you should import the addon as a module import my_addon or from my_addon import X.
If you want your addon to be importable without bpy like to be able to from my_addon import utils where utils is a non-bpy module. Move all the top level import in __init__.py inside register() and unregister() functions. So when you import my_addon it does not import any Blender's modules.
bl_info = {
    "name": "test",
    "author": "test",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "category": "Generic",
}


from . import this_module_DOES_NOT_use_bpy


@this_module_DOES_NOT_use_bpy.time_it
def register():
    import bpy

    from . import this_module_DOES_use_bpy
    bpy.utils.register_class(this_module_DOES_use_bpy.TEST_OT_test)

    this_module_DOES_NOT_use_bpy.do_this()


def unregister():
    import bpy

    from . import this_module_DOES_use_bpy
    bpy.utils.register_class(this_module_DOES_use_bpy.TEST_OT_test)

    this_module_DOES_NOT_use_bpy.do_that()



Thanks ... I had thought I tried that. One issue is that two of the files in the import refer to each other, so however I set it up, either the Blender import didn't work or my tests wouldn't run. The two files were small so for now I've just combined them. I will have to study package as I have not learned that yet. Your final paragraph is over my head, my fault, not yours. I'll study ore. Thanks!
